# Why isn't apache serving the page? mod_rewrite seems to have found the right file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

The project I'm working on has a fairly long & complicated list of RewriteRules, separated into 2 .htaccess files for legacy reasons. I'm putting the app into a Docker container to make it easier to on-board new developers, but the Ubuntu/Apache combo is choking on the RewriteRules and giving me an HTTP 500.

Docker image: php:5.6-Apache
Apache Version: 2.4

I boosted the logging to trace4 and it appears to figure out the right file - here's the last line of the mod_rewrite debug output

```
[Thu Mar 16 09:08:15.459987 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 17] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 192.168.99.1:63990] 192.168.99.1 - - [rs.dev/sid#7f51cf6fece0][rid#7f51cf61c8f8/initial/redir#3] [perdir /var/www/appname/public_html/production/] pass through /var/www/appname/public_html/production/login.php
```

The file '/var/www/appname/public_html/production/login.php' exists, and is the file that should be loaded. However, the response is sent as a 500, (and the page doesn't load). I'm using the /login URL here as an example, but it happens on all URLs.

This works on the localhost of a Mac running macOS, and it works in cPanel servers, I just can't seem to get it running in the Ubuntu base that Docker's providing me.

Does anyone know why Apache would use mod_rewrite and appear to identify the correct file, but then not use the file?

For reference, the entire log output from the request [is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NDkqvai5).

Comment: I suspect the actual error thrown, that leads to the http status 500, is independent from the rewriting process. What does your http servers error log file say about the requests?

Comment: The 500 would indicate that there is an issue with login.php not the apache rewrite. Try making an http request to that resource directly. Check the Apache error log. Share the PHP file.

Comment: "pass through" doesn't mean it has identified or found anything, just that it puts it back to the general processing.

Comment: I was going to post something snarky for @WilliamGreenly about how 500 errors can come from other places too, but then I figured I would triple-check that PHP wasn't the problem, and lo and behold it was! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, (my logs weren't catching PHP errors last night).

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for the info - Google wasn't much help looking for details on those logs. If you know where to find details I'm still interested.

Comment: @JohnB Usually, I just refer to Apache's documentation. For mod_rewrite and how it works, this is [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) itself and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/. From the link list there are [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html), [Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html), [Ruleset Processing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset). It takes time of course, but once you get it, it isn't too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my problem wasn't in the Rewriting at all, I had forgotten to create a file that PHP was trying to `require`, so it was throwing a PHP error. However, the way the logs were configured, the error was disappearing into the ether, (or into a log I haven't found yet).

Let that be a lesson - even if you're *absolutely sure* where the error is, you might still be wrong!